# find headings from multiple text files in one location and add to xlsx document with same headings

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7

I need to create a Python program that will read through multiple .txt files in a set directory, then look for specific headings from within the text files and store the data found under the headings from the searched text in a .xlsx document

*An example of a .txt file*

```
person:         Vyacheslav Danik
address:        Ukraine, Kharkov
phone:          +380675746805
address:        Ukraine, Kharkiv
address:        Pavlova st., 319
```

I need 5 Headers in the excel spreadsheet; number, organization, role, name, and address. And for the python program to put information under these headings in the spreadsheet from each file scanned.

Any help would be appreciated, as I'm struggling a bit with this. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO: Please take the [tour] and read [MCVE]. Your question is far too broad for this forum and you likely won't get all the answers you need. You can always hire some help. I'll write your code for $5 and some beer :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm still a beginner myself, but I thought this seemed easy enough. Its more of a starting point for you to build on and customize. I only choose to do one column (Person), I'm pretty sure everything you need to do what you want is in this example. You'll have to install the 2 required python libraries needed to access spreadsheets by running the next 2 commands (assuming you're using some type of linux, you didn't provide enough info):

> pip install xlrd
>
> pip install xlutils

Here's the example, the comments roughly explain what each line does.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

''' Required to install these libraries to access spreadsheets
pip install xlrd
pip install xlutils
'''

import os, re, string

from xlutils.copy import copy    
from xlrd import open_workbook

book_ro = open_workbook("spreadsheet.xls")

# creates a writeable copy
book = copy(book_ro)

# Select first sheet
sheet1 = book.get_sheet(0)

# Create list to hold people, otherwise we have to figure out the next empty column in spreadsheet
peopleList = []

# Get list of files in current folder and filter only the txt files
for root, dirs, docs in os.walk('.', topdown=True):            

    for filename in docs:
            if (filename.endswith(".txt")) or (filename.endswith(".TXT")):
                filepath=(os.path.join(root, name))

                # Open file read only
                TxtFile = open(filepath,"r")

                # Read all the lines at once in variable
                lines = TxtFile.readlines()
                
                # Finished reading, close file
                TxtFile.close()

                # Convert file to big string so it can be searched with re.findall
                lines = '\n'.join(lines)

                # Find all occurences of "person:" and capture rest of line
                people = re.findall(r'person: (.*)',lines)

                # Remove delimeters/special character separating each name
                people = map(lambda x: x.strip(), people)

                # If file has more than 1 person, add each one individually
                for person in people:
                    peopleList.append(person)

row = 0
column = 0

# Sort the list and remove duplicates (set(sort)), then step thru list and write to spreadsheet
for person in set(sorted(peopleList)):
    sheet1.write(row, column, person)
    row += 1

# This will overwrite the original spreadsheet if one existed
book.save("spreadsheet.xls")
```